# Cocoa drawing, "lock" mouse on special events

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, graphics, drawing

With a little help from the last question regarding drawings in Cocoa i've implemented some basic shapes, as well as dragging / resizing.

So, right now i'm trying to figure out, how to create a effect like in Keynote when a shape is resized and it automatically fits the size of another shape next to it and then "locks" the mouse for a bit of time.

The first attempt is to use a delay function, like

```
NSDate *future = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 0.5 ];
[NSThread sleepUntilDate:future];
```

reacting on the desired event (e. g. shape width == height). But this results not in the desired effect, since the whole App freezes for the specified amount of time. In addition to that i think, that the user won't recognize it as something saying "you've reached a special size". Showing guidelines only at the event is not a solution, since the guidelines are shown as soon as the shape is selected.

Comment: You definitely don't want to sleep. I'm not 100% sure if I've got the right idea, though -- let me describe what I am picturing. We have two square shapes next to each other. Square A on the left is slightly smaller and separated from Square B on the right by a small distance. When we drag the lower-right resize handle of Square A down and towards B, the handle will "pause" if it hits either of the lines defined by B's left and lower edges. I.e., the user can drag the mouse, but the handle does not move, and A does not continue resizing, for a moment. "Snap to guides", in other words?

Comment: @Josh: No sleep until this is fixed...ok, maybe a bit sleep ;) "Snap to guides", you nailed it. There is a question about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577453/snap-to-grid-effect-with-quartz-2d-iphone-dev), but this does not consider the "pause"-effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For snap to guides, I don't think you actually want the *cursor* to stop. Just that the resizing should stop reacting to the cursor movements, within a small range of your target.

The solution in [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577453/snap-to-grid-effect-with-quartz-2d-iphone-dev) is more or less what you want, I think. Essentially, when you get close enough to the guide, you just change the point's coordinates to those of the guide. So, building on the sample code I posted in your earlier question, this becomes your view's `mouseDragged:`, and `mouseUp:`. You can leave the new checks out of `mouseDragged:` if you want the point to snap only on mouse up, a different but just as valid behavior.

If you're matching the edges of rectangles, you'll probably find the [Foundation Rect Functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIJBHDI), like `NSMaxX` and `NSMaxY`, useful.

```
- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event {
    if( !currMovingDot ) return;
    NSPoint spot = [self convertPoint:[event locationInWindow] 
                             fromView:nil];
    spot.x = MAX(0, MIN(spot.x, self.bounds.size.width));
    spot.y = MAX(0, MIN(spot.y, self.bounds.size.height));

    // Look for Dots whose centerlines are close to
    // the current mouse position
    for( Dot * dot in dots ){
        if (dot == currMovingDot) {
            // Don't snap to myself! Leaving this out causes
            // "snap to grid" effect.
            continue;
        }
        // Where SNAP_DIST is #define'd somewhere
        // something under 10 seems to be a good value
        if( abs(spot.x - dot.position.x) <= SNAP_DIST ){
            spot.x = dot.position.x;
        }
        if( abs(spot.y - dot.position.y) <= SNAP_DIST ){
            spot.y = dot.position.y;
        }
    } 


    currMovingDot.position = spot;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Comment: So it's entirely all about rounding and providing the right mouse behaviour (i. e. **not** locking). Thanks Josh, helpful as always.

Comment: @macs: You're quite welcome; it's a pleasure. BTW, I was playing around with the rect edges matching up; it may be a little trickier than it seems at first glance. Good luck!

Comment: I noticed that. I also wanted to avoid having the user pressing a key if he/she does not want to use this feature. But it seems that this will be the only way. The main intention for the question was also to avoid writing a class for circles or squares, i think it's better to generate a square with the assistance of the app. I could notify you, if i'm having a good basis. This one will become great :)